# Find an expression for the area under the graph of f(x) as a limit?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, area

$f(x) = \frac{2x}{x^2 +1}, 1 \leq x \leq 3$

Basically, I need to find an expression for the area under the graph within these intervals for the function as a limit.

I understand the concept of the area for this problem being...

$\lim_{n \to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i})\Delta x$

Hence for this problem I imagined it would be...

$ \lim_{n \to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\frac{2x_{i}}{x_{i}^2 + 1} . \Delta x$

Only I don't know how you would work out Delta x?

The answers in the book says
$\lim_{n \to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2(1+2i/n)}{(1+2i/n)^2+1}.\frac{2}{n}$

Can anyone explain to me how this is worked out and where all the Ns come from? Possibly missing something obvious here...

Comment: Here is what the book did:
$$\Delta x = \dfrac{b-a}{n} = \dfrac{3-1}{n} = \dfrac{2}{n}$$
And
$$x_i = a+i\Delta x = 1+\dfrac{2i}{n}$$
Then just make the substitutions

Answer (score 1):

The book uses  $\Delta x = \frac2n$ and $x_i=1+i\Delta x = 1+\frac{2i}n$ so that $x_1=1+\frac2n\approx 1$ and $x_n=1+\frac{2n}n=3$ and plugs this into $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2x_i}{x_i^2+1}\cdot\Delta x$